# Double get in axios and putting data into interface

Tags: axios, request, get

I have 2 tables:

```
itinerary:

name: string;
dateStart: String;
dateEnd: String;
cityId: String;
userEmail: string;
locationsId: String[];
userId: String[];


city:String;
```

and

```
location:

name:string;
country:string;
```

I extracted the data from the table Itinerary with axios in the code below:

```
interface Itinerary {
  name: string;
  dateStart: String;
  dateEnd: String;
  cityId: String;
  userEmail: string;
  locationsId: String[];
  userId: String[];
}
export const ItineraryContext = React.createContext<Itinerary[]>([]);
const [itinerary, setItinerary] = useState<Itinerary[]>([]);


axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/itineraries/e/${userid}`) 
      .then((res) => {
        for (let key in res.data) {
          itinerary.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key });
        }
        setItinerary(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });


    // itinerary.map((item)=>  axios
    // .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/cities/id/${item.cityId}`)
    // .then((res) => {
    //   item.city=res;
    // })
    // )


  }, []);
```

I want to make another api request with get, in order to get the name of the city(right know I have only the idCity) and to put it in the `city field from Itinerary[]`

I tried what you see commented at the end of the code, but I don't know how to put the value that I get into Itinerary[] interface...